# Image on vertical or horizontal center of border with padding

Tags: html, css, image, border, center

I have a border, which fits 100% width of container div. What I want to do - add background (or `img` tag) in center of that border, like in example:

http://www.part.lt/img/8a22897d62de874896a3b62107032bd3507.gif

(The "+" is image and line from left and right must be border). White space must be padding or margin from border.

How can I do this?

What I have tried:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHVbc)

```
<div class="full-border">
   <div class="full-border-cross"></div>
</div>


.full-border {
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204,204,204);
     padding: 13px 0; 
     position: relative;
}

.full-border-cross {
     background: #fff url(http://www.part.lt/img/21ea608f463d841dd48f2a856ef7d0d4993.png) no-repeat center center;
     position: absolute; 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; padding: 0 13px;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have no idea, what i can do...

Comment: SO is to help you, not to do sth for you. Show some code doing as nearly to what you need, as you are able to create. You can also try backgrounds, maybe bg image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WHVbc/ - There is something, what i try, but it's just primary work.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there (as code).

Comment: It is everything good now?

Comment: I really want to help you out bud but I am real unclear what your asking. You want the plus sign to be positioned a certain way so it  becomes the border? Like the horizontal line is the border repeating across the width?

Comment: all of this border must be 100% width of parrent and plus sign must be in center of it. The solution with white background isn't good, because this div will be in some parrent divs with different backgrounds (images, gradients and etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Does the white space "have" to be padding? or can you just assign it a certain width?

I've updated your fiddle with this code:

```
.full-border-cross {
     background: url(http://www.part.lt/img/21ea608f463d841dd48f2a856ef7d0d4993.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
     position: absolute; 
     left: 50%;
     width: 40px; 
     height: 100%;
}
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/WHVbc/17/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your requirement below and also available in the following fiddle. Refer that...

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/wRa8n/

```
<div class="full-border"></div>
<div class="full-border-cross"></div>
<div class="full-border"></div>

.full-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 16px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

.full-border-cross {
    background: url("http://www.part.lt/img/21ea608f463d841dd48f2a856ef7d0d4993.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 13px;
    width: 15px;
}
```